# Gamecenter delegate not being called when players join

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, game-center

I've been trying to figure out how to add gamecenter to my game. I'm able to make a match and when players join the match I expected `-(void)match:player:didChangeState:` to be called. I thought maybe my delegate wasn't set for some reason. I tried to test it with this code:

```
-(void)checkDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"Self.myMatch.delegate %@",self.myMatch.delegate);
}
```

NSLog outputs `<MultiplayerGameLayer = 0x651fd80 | Tag = -1>` as it should. Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: Some more info. The delegate does get called when one of the devices disconnects. It just doesn't get called when the players join.

Comment: What happens if you just print `self.myMatch.delegate` without calling the description method? You might have implemented the `description` method in your class without returning anything.

Comment: Are you sure `(null)` comes from that NSLog? Try add some random text before `%@` like `NSLog (@"test: %@")` and try print `self.myMatch`

Comment: self.myMatch is (null) also. I'll try and see why that is